# "NoMethodError: undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass" when Unit Testing Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, model

I am creating a Rails app (fairly new at this), and I have a Client model that I generated without using scaffolding. I have run 'rake db:migrate', and I am unit testing the model with 'rake test:units', however I am getting variations of the following runtime error in terminal for practically all of my factory testing.

```
test: Creating seven clients should show that all factories are properly created. (ClientTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass
    /Users/myUserName/Desktop/app_name/test/unit/client_test.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ClientTest>'
```

I have been unable to figure out what the error is. I understand that it doesn't recognize the client class and thus it can't find the 'destroy' method for nil. However, I'm unsure of how to fix it.

Below is my model code, located in app_name/app/models/client.rb

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Callbacks
  before_save :reformat_phone

  # Relationships
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :counselors, :through => :assignments
  has_many :interventions, :through => :assignments

  # Validations
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :phone, :active
  validates_inclusion_of :gender, :in => %w[male female], :message => "is not an option"
  validates_inclusion_of :marital_status, :in => %w[single married separated divorced], :message => "is not an option"
  validates_inclusion_of :state, :in => %w[PA OH WV], :message => "is not an option"
  validates_format_of :zip, :with => /^\d{5}$/, :message => "should be five digits long"
  validates_format_of :phone, :with => /^\(?\d{3}\)?[-. ]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}$/, :message => "should be 10 digits (area code needed) and delimited with dashes only"

  # Scopes
  scope :active, where('active = ?', true)
  scope :inactive, where('active = ?', false)
  scope :alphabetical, order('last_name, first_name')

  scope :receiving_gov_assistance, where('gov_assistance = ?', true)
  scope :not_receiving_gov_assistance, where('gov_assistance = ?', false)

  scope :male, where('gender = ?', 'male')
  scope :female, where('gender = ?', 'female')

  scope :by_marital_status, lambda { |status| where("marital_status = ?", status) }
  scope :by_ethnicity, lambda { |race| where("ethnicity = ?", race) }

  scope :employed, where('is_employed = ?', true)
  scope :unemployed, where('is_employed = ?', false)

  scope :veteran, where('is_veteran = ?', true)

  scope :assigned, where('current_assignment != ?', nil)
  scope :unassigned, where('current_assignment = ?', nil) 

# Other methods
  def name
    "#{last_name}, #{first_name}"
  end

  def proper_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

  def current_assignment
    curr_assignment = self.assignments.select{|a| a.end_date.nil?}
    # alternative method for finding current assignment is to use scope 'current' in assignments:
    # curr_assignment = self.assignments.current    # will also return an array of current assignments
    return nil if curr_assignment.empty?
    curr_assignment.first   # return as a single object, not an array
  end

  # Misc Constants
  GENDER_LIST = [['Male', 'male'],['Female', 'female']]
  STATES_LIST = [['Ohio', 'OH'],['Pennsylvania', 'PA'],['West Virginia', 'WV']]

  # Callback code
  # -----------------------------
  private
  def reformat_phone
    phone = self.phone.to_s  # change to string in case input as all numbers 
    phone.gsub!(/[^0-9]/,"") # strip all non-digits
    self.phone = phone       # reset self.phone to new string
  end
end
```

And here are the tests I've written, located in app_name/test/unit/client_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class ClientTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Test relationships
  should have_many(:assignments)
  should have_many(:deacons).through(:assignments)
  should have_many(:interventions).through(:assignments)

  # Test basic validations
  should validate_presence_of(:last_name)
  should validate_presence_of(:first_name)
  should validate_presence_of(:gender)
  should validate_presence_of(:address)
  should validate_presence_of(:city)
  should validate_presence_of(:state)
  should validate_presence_of(:zip)
  should validate_presence_of(:phone)
  should validate_presence_of(:active)

  # Identity-based tests
      # tests for gender
      should allow_value("male").for(:gender)
      should allow_value("female").for(:gender)

      should_not allow_value(nil).for(:gender)
      should_not allow_value(1).for(:gender)
      should_not allow_value("seahorse").for(:gender)
      should_not allow_value("I believe gender is a societal construct.").for(:gender)

      # tests for ethnicity
      should allow_value("Asian").for(:ethnicity)
      should allow_value("Black").for(:ethnicity)
      should allow_value("Hispanic").for(:ethnicity)
      should allow_value("Latino").for(:ethnicity)
      should allow_value("Native American").for(:ethnicity)
      should allow_value("White").for(:ethnicity)

      should_not allow_value(nil).for(:ethnicity)
      should_not allow_value(1).for(:ethnicity)
      should_not allow_value(true).for(:ethnicity)
      should_not allow_value(0.5).for(:ethnicity)

      # tests for marital status
      should allow_value("single").for(:marital_status)
      should allow_value("married").for(:marital_status)
      should allow_value("separated").for(:marital_status)
      should allow_value("divorced").for(:marital_status)

      should_not allow_value("White").for(:marital_status)
      should_not allow_value(nil).for(:marital_status)
      should_not allow_value(1).for(:marital_status)
      should_not allow_value(true).for(:marital_status)
      should_not allow_value("I believe marriage is a societal construct.").for(:marital_status)

  # Contact-based Tests
      # tests for address
      should allow_value("123 Example Lane").for(:address)
      should allow_value("456 Another Street").for(:address)

      should_not allow_value(true).for(:address)
      should_not allow_value(101).for(:address)
      should_not allow_value(nil).for(:address)

      # tests for zip
      should allow_value("12345").for(:zip)

      should_not allow_value("bad").for(:zip)
      should_not allow_value("1234").for(:zip)
      should_not allow_value("123456").for(:zip)
      should_not allow_value("12345-6789").for(:zip)

      # tests for state
      should allow_value("OH").for(:state)
      should allow_value("PA").for(:state)
      should allow_value("WV").for(:state)
      should_not allow_value("bad").for(:state)
      should_not allow_value("NY").for(:state)
      should_not allow_value(10).for(:state)
      should_not allow_value("CA").for(:state)

      # tests for phone
      should allow_value("4122683259").for(:phone)
      should allow_value("412-268-3259").for(:phone)
      should allow_value("412.268.3259").for(:phone)
      should allow_value("(412) 268-3259").for(:phone)
      should_not allow_value("2683259").for(:phone)
      should_not allow_value("14122683259").for(:phone)
      should_not allow_value("4122683259x224").for(:phone)
      should_not allow_value("800-EAT-FOOD").for(:phone)
      should_not allow_value("412/268/3259").for(:phone)
      should_not allow_value("412-2683-259").for(:phone)

  # Assistance-based tests
      # tests for gov_assistance
      should allow_value(true).for(:gov_assistance)
      should allow_value(false).for(:gov_assistance)

      should_not allow_value(150).for(:gov_assistance)
      should_not allow_value("Yes").for(:gov_assistance)

      # tests for is_employed
      should allow_value(true).for(:is_employed)
      should allow_value(false).for(:is_employed)

      should_not allow_value(30000).for(:is_employed)
      should_not allow_value("Movie theater usher").for(:is_employed)

      # tests for is_veteran
      should allow_value(true).for(:is_veteran)
      should allow_value(false).for(:is_veteran)

      should_not allow_value(nil).for(:is_veteran)
      should_not allow_value("Marines").for(:is_veteran)

  # Establish context
  # Testing other methods with a context
  context "Creating seven clients" do
    setup do 
      @dan = FactoryGirl.create(:client)
      @barney = FactoryGirl.create(:client, :last_name => "Saha", :first_name => "Barney", :active => false, :ethnicity => "Indian" )
      @ryan = FactoryGirl.create(:client, :last_name => "Black", :first_name => "Ryan", :phone => "412-867-5309", :ethnicity => "White", :gov_assistance => true )
      @joe = FactoryGirl.create(:client, :last_name => "Oak", :first_name => "Joseph", :ethnicity => "Asian", :is_employed => false )
      @mary = FactoryGirl.create(:client, :last_name => "Clute", :first_name => "Mary", :gender => "female", :ethnicity => "White" )
      @jon = FactoryGirl.create(:client, :last_name => "Carreon", :first_name => "Jon", :is_veteran => true )
      @meg = FactoryGirl.create(:client, :last_name => "Smith", :first_name => "Megan", :ethnicity => "White", :gender => "female", :is_employed => false)
    end

    # and provide a teardown method as well
    teardown do
      @dan.destroy
      @barney.destroy
      @ryan.destroy
      @joe.destroy
      @mary.destroy
      @jon.destroy
      @meg.destroy
    end

    # test one of each factory
    should "show that all factories are properly created" do
      assert_equal "Tabrizi", @dan.last_name
      assert @ryan.active
      assert @joe.active
      assert_equal "Mary", @mary.first_name
      assert @jon.active
      assert @meg.active
      deny @barney.active
    end

    # test the callback is working 'reformat_phone'
    should "shows that Ryan's phone is stripped of non-digits" do
      assert_equal "4128675309", @ryan.phone
    end

    # test the scope 'alphabetical'
    should "shows that there are seven clients in in alphabetical order" do
      assert_equal ["Black", "Carreon", "Clute", "Oak", "Saha", "Smith", "Tabrizi"], Client.alphabetical.map{|s| s.last_name}
    end

    # test the scope 'active'
    should "shows that there are six active clients" do
      assert_equal 2, Client.active.size
      assert_equal ["Black", "Carreon", "Clute", "Oak", "Smith", "Tabrizi"], Client.active.alphabetical.map{|s| s.last_name}
    end

    # test the scope 'inactive'
    should "shows that there is one inactive client" do
      assert_equal 1, Client.inactive.size
      assert_equal ["Saha"], Client.inactive.alphabetical.map{|s| s.last_name}
    end

    # test the scope 'receiving_gov_assistance'
    should "shows that there is one client receiving government assistance" do
      assert_equal 1, Client.receiving_gov_assistance.size
      assert_equal ["Black"], Client.receiving_gov_assistance.alphabetical.map{|s| s.last_name}
    end

    # test the scope 'not_receiving_gov_assistance'
    should "shows that there are six clients not receiving government assistance" do
      assert_equal 6, Client.not_receiving_gov_assistance.size
      assert_equal ["Carreon", "Clute", "Oak", "Saha", "Smith", "Tabrizi"], Client.not_receiving_gov_assistance.alphabetical.map{|s| s.last_name}
    end

    # test the scope 'male'
    should "shows that there are five male clients" do
      assert_equal 6, Client.male.size
      assert_equal ["Black", "Carreon", "Oak", "Saha", "Tabrizi"], Client.male.alphabetical.map{|s| s.last_name}
    end

    # test the scope 'female'
    should "shows that there are two female clients" do
      assert_equal 2, Client.female.size
      assert_equal ["Clute", "Smith"], Client.female.alphabetical.map{|s| s.last_name}
    end

    # test the scope 'employed'
    should "shows that there are five employed clients" do
      assert_equal 5, Client.employed.size
      assert_equal ["Black", "Carreon", "Clute", "Saha", "Tabrizi"], Client.employed.alphabetical.map{|s| s.last_name}
    end

    # test the scope 'unemployed'
    should "shows that there are two unemployed clients" do
      assert_equal 2, Client.unemployed.size
      assert_equal ["Oak", "Smith"], Client.unemployed.alphabetical.map{|s| s.last_name}
    end

    # test the scope 'veteran'
    should "shows that there is one employed clients" do
      assert_equal 1, Client.veteran.size
      assert_equal ["Carreon"], Client.veteran.alphabetical.map{|s| s.last_name}
    end

    # test the method 'name' #DONE
    should "shows name as last, first name" do
      assert_equal "Tabrizi, Dan", @dan.name
    end   

    # test the method 'proper_name' #DONE
    should "shows proper name as first and last name" do
      assert_equal "Dan Tabrizi", @dan.proper_name
    end 

  end
end
```

Thank you very much for your help. If there are any other files that are necessary to determine the issue, please let me know. Sorry if this is very simple or too vague, I'm new to Rails development and I am using the terminology to the best of my knowledge

EDIT

Below is my client factory as it currently stands, in app_name/test/factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :client do
    last_name "Tabrizi"
    first_name "Dan"
    gender "male"
    ethnicity "Hispanic"
    marital_status "single"
    address "123 Example Lane"
    city "Anytown"
    state "PA"
    zip "12345"
    phone { rand(10 ** 10).to_s.rjust(10,'0') }
    gov_assistance false
    is_employed true
    is_veteran false
    active true
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for your `:client` factory?

Comment: Try removing your `teardown` block. `FactoryGirl should do it for you.`

Comment: The client factory code is above now. I also changed the teardown method to the suggestion below, however I received the error that I outline below now. Any leads to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you perform tests against separate test database, so it is safe to do:

```
teardown do
  Client.destroy_all
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately since doing that, now I am running into a different error

`test: Creating seven clients should show that all factories are properly created. (ClientTest):
LoadError: Expected /Users/myUserName/Desktop/app_name/app/models/deacon.rb to define Deacon`

Deacon is another model I have (replace counselors with it in the above model code). So it's expecting the Deacon model, but I've only been testing for Client (I commented out all other tests besides client, just to deal with this right now). Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Messed around more and got it working. It ultimately was due to other things I had going on, but altering the teardown was the lynchpin. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You welcome! But as others suggested, in ideal situation `teardown` metod should be removed, because FactoryGirl should perform transactional creation and rollback after tests.

Answer (score 0):

Like Simon suggested, try commenting out or removing your teardown. Usually in these situations teardown masks what the real error is, because it will compile all your code and try to initiate the destroy method which will fail because your factories will have returned nil. Since that happens it will return the last error that was documented, which is why your receiving that error.